# Need help converting htaccess to ISAPI_Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

Does anyone can help me converting these rules to [ISAPI_Rewrite]. Thanks.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately directive RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f is a new feature from version 3 that is not supported by version 2. The only workaround - to list all real folders like (?: folder1|folder2|folder3|etc).

1) Don't forget to put the following on top of the config file:

```
[ISAPI_Rewrite]
```

2) The second rule should work fine. Maybe you'll need to do:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [I,L]
```